# Как обойти запрет на максимальное количество отправленных данных на сервер за раз?

Tags: база-данных, sql-server, angularjs

Здравствуйте! Проблема заключается в следующем:

Существует база данных, на сервере стоит ограничение на максимальное количество передаваемых данных за раз в размере 3000 записей. Созданы функции для передачи данных на сервер.

```
       function chunkArray(arr, chunk) {
                var i, j, tmp = [];
                for (i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; i += chunk) {
                    tmp.push(arr.slice(i, i + chunk));
                }
                return tmp;
            }
            //на сервере рассылок стоит ограничение в 3000 записей за раз поэтому делем результирющий массив на части
            var splitedArr = chunkArray(arrPersonalAccStr, 3000);

            splitedArr.forEach(function (item, index, arr) {

                if (index == 0) {                     // для проверки отправки (временно)
                    console.log('0 -send'); 
                    sendArrPersonalAcc(item);         // отправляем
                }
                if (index == 1) {                     // для проверки отправки (временно)
                    console.log('1 -send');
                    sendArrPersonalAcc(item);         // отправляем
                }
                if (index == 2) {                     // для проверки отправки (временно)
                    console.log('2 -send');
                    sendArrPersonalAcc(item);         // отправляем
                }

            });

            function sendArrPersonalAcc(arr) {
                //console.log(arr);
                $http.post('EmailSubscription/SendEmailContacts', arr)
                 .then(function (result) {
                     var responseCount = result.data.totalsubscribersResult;
                     function getSended(data) {
                       return  angular.isDefined(data) ? result.data.totalsubscribersResult : 0
                     }
                     $scope.totalsubscribers += getSended(responseCount); //Если все ок указываем количество отправленных контактов
                 },
                 function (err) {  });
            }
```

В следствии чего, насколько я понимаю, массив передается на сервак сразу всей пачкой, поэтому уже после 3000 записей всё сбивается и ничего не происходит.Для того чтобы этого не происходило приходится с помощью созданных фильтров отбирать данные для прередачи и после отправлять. Но суть не в этом. Вопрос в том, как же всё таки организовать поочередную передачу данных на сервер, чтобы за раз можно было передать сразу всю пачку?

Comment: Очевидно, соответствующим образом модифицировать серверную часть.

Comment: Мне кажется у вас проблема в том, что Вы пытаетесь разбить массив на части и делаете просто 3 запроса подряд. Возможно из-за этого захлёбывается сервер. Попробуйте, делать очередную отправку пакета, только после того, как придёт подтверждение о доставке предыдущего. Вообщем, воспользуйтесь ``promise``.